# PayTm: checksum mismatch Error Code : 330

Tags: plugins, checksum, paytm

Trying to generate hybrid .apk from phone gap. And using PHP language to generate paytm "checksum".

At Server Side PHP page:

```
// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["ENVIRONMENT"] = "staging";
$paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = "APPSTAGING";


//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
```

After getting the checksum value; checkSum is used for transaction.

```
  var options = {
                            ENVIRONMENT: "staging",
                            MID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            ORDER_ID: "ORDER0000000001",
                            CUST_ID: "10000988111",
                            INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail",
                            CHANNEL_ID: "WAP",
                            TXN_AMOUNT: "1.50",
                            WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING",
                            CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDER0000000001",

                            CHECKSUMHASH: checkSum // php code generated checksum.

                       };

                        paytm.startPayment(options, app.successCallPayTm, app.failureCallPayTm);
```

When create the app for the same; it always shows the issue "Error Code: 330; PayTm checksum mismatch".

Please anyone guide.